# Errors when running Apps in ASP.NET MVC CORE

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I am recently set up Visual Studio 2017, but
When i try to start ASP.NET MVC CORE Project that runtime error appears:

**System.MissingMethodException occurred
HResult=0x80131513
Message=Method not found: 'System.IServiceProvider Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'.
Source=
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
at WebApplication4.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\qqq\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Program.cs:line 14**

and when i try to run another ASP.NET MVC CORE Project this error message  appears:

**Unable to start process C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe. The web server request failed with status code 500, Internal Server Error. The full response has been written to C:\Users\qqq\AppData\Local\Temp\HttpFailure_04-02-08.html.**

Are these errors because of IIS Error or something in configuration ?

Comment: Please revise the title to describe your specific problem. "Error in Visual Studio 2017" is extremely vague. Another person with the same problem would have no way of knowing that this question applies to their problem.